# condicion if no analiza si el valor es diferente entre si en python

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]De antemano gracias a quien me pueda aclarar lo siguiente:

Tengo un arreglo de tres elementos en una lista y cada elemento es una lista de tres elementos:
Deseo recorrer cada elemento y determinar si el valor tiene "X" o "O" no debe hacer nada de lo contrario debe crearme una tupla con las coordenadas de ese espacio de matriz. Resulta que si coloco en el if que la posición sea diferente "X" o "O" me reconoce como si todas fueran diferentes cuando en realidad algunos espacios si contienen estos valores,  pero lo extraño es que si lo analizo tomándolos como iguales "X" o "O" si hace la lógico correctamente: ¿Alguien me podría por favor aclarar por que sucede eso o que se me esta escapando?

```py
#Opcion Codigo UNO 

board  =[["X","O",3],[4,'X',6],[7,8,9]]
def disponibles(board):
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if board[i][j] != "X" or board[i][j] != "O":
                Tupla1=(i,j)
                print(Tupla1)

disponibles(board)
```

Gracias!!!!

Comment: Cambia `or` por `and`

Comment: El problema está en la lógica, cuando pones que sea diferente de "X" o diferente de "O" cualquier condición se cumple. Por ejemplo, tienes una "X" en el primer elemento de la primera sublista, al compararse con tu condición primero pregunta, es diferente de "X", la respuesta es `False` y luego hace la segunda parte, o es diferente de "O" y la respuesta es `True` porque "X" es diferente de "O", por eso todo te devuelve `True` tienes que usar `and` como dice @Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como ya te han explicado el problema es que debías usar `and` en vez de `or`.

La confusión es típica, porque en el fondo tú piensas "la posición está ocupada si contiene X **o** contiene O", y por tanto deduces (errónamente) que lo contrario será: "La posición NO está ocupadasi NO contiene X **o** NO contiene O".

Pero esto no es correcto porque en lógica la negación de (A or B) no es (¬A or ¬B), sino (¬A and ¬B). Esta es la Ley de De Morgan.

Para evitar este tipo de confusiones puede ser más sencillo reformular la condición simplemente escribiendo la condición que te dice cuando es está ocupada, y poniendo un `not` delante:

```
not (valor == "X" or valor == "O")
```

Por alguna razón nos resulta más fácil leer y comprender esta sintaxis que usar la ley de De Morgan.

### Mejoras progresivas en el código

Así pues una primera mejora para la legibilidad sería escribir tu función así:

```py
def disponibles(board):
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if not (board[i][j] == "X" or board[i][j] == "O"):
                print((i,j))
```

Aún así la condición del `if` queda larga y farragosa. En el fondo queremos chequear si la posición no está ocupada, así que quedaría mucho más legible si simplemente escribimos:

```py
def disponibles(board):
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if not ocupada(board[i][j]):
                print(i,j)
```

y sólo nos queda escribir la función `ocupada()` que recibe el contenido de una casilla y devuelve si es válida:

```
def ocupada(c):
    return c=="X" or c=="O"
```

Que también puede escribirse de esta otra forma, más útil si los posibles casos válidos son muchos:

```
def ocupada(c):
    return c in ("X", "O")
```

Por otro lado, los dos bucles anidados provocan una indentación progresiva del código que lo hace difícil de leer, y se puede evitar con ayuda de la librería `itertools` (estándar Python), que te permite dejarlo así:

```
from itertools import product
def disponibles(board):
    for i,j in product(range(3), range(3)):
        if not ocupada(board[i][j]):
            print((i,j))
```

gracias a la cual hemos eliminado un nivel de indentación. La función `product()` se ocupa de iterar los bucles anidados, devolviéndote en cada iteración una tupla. La secuencia de tuplas que `product()` te irá devolviendo en este caso serán `(0,0)`, `(0,1)`, `(0,2)`, `(1,0)`, `(1,1)`, `(1,2)`, `(2,0)`, `(2,1)` y `(2,2)`, por lo que el bucle aquí usado equivale a tus dos bucles anidados. La ganancia en legibilidad es tanto mayor cuantas más variables tengas que anidar (más dimensiones de la matriz).

Finalmente, se puede usar una comprensión de listas para que las tuplas que se vayan generando, en lugar de imprimirlas, se vayan guardando en una lista, y que la función `disponibles()` retorne la lista resultante. Las comprensiones de listas permiten comprimir en una sola línea de código un bucle que vaya añadiendo elementos a una lista, y una condición de qué elementos deben ser añadidos. En este caso quedaría así:

```
def disponibles(board):
    return [(i,j) for i,j in product(range(3),range(3)) if not ocupada(board[i][j])]
```

Y la llamarías por ejemplo así: `print(disponibles(board))` lo que produciría en tu tablero de ejemplo:

```
[(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

La legibilidad es importante. Evita muchos bugs y hace la vida más fácil a quien más adelante tenga que leer y comprender tu código. Y ten en cuenta que ese alguien puedes ser tú!

Comment: Pues amigo me has dado una clase que vale oro y a cambio solo de mi gratitud, muchas gracias por compartir tu conocimiento, estoy iniciando pero por supuesto la  idea es dirigirnos por el camino del clean code.

Answer (score 0):

La condición se debe probar con un "and", ya que el contenido debe ser distinto de "X" **y** de "O".

```
board  =[["X","O",3],[4,'X',6],[7,8,9]]
def disponibles(board):
    for i in range(0,3):
        for j in range(0,3):
            if board[i][j] != "X" and board[i][j] != "O":
                Tupla1=(i,j)
                print(Tupla1)

disponibles(board)
```

produce:

```
(0, 2)
(1, 0)
(1, 2)
(2, 0)
(2, 1)
(2, 2)
```